# Is there a good criterion to determine if a polynomial with integer or rational coefficients is irreducible over the field of p-adic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. As $\mathbb{Q}$ can be embedded into the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any prime $p$, the polynomial $f$ can also be considered as an polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

**Question**: Is there a good (sufficient or characterizing) criterion to determine whether $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or not?

**Motivation**: In Chapter 10 of [these lecture notes on local fields](http://www.pancratz.org/notes/Local.pdf), it turns out that $L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})$ has ramification degree $e_{L/\mathbb{Q}_p}\geq 2$, so $[L:\mathbb{Q}_p] = 2$. This must mean that the polynomial $f = x^2 - p$ must be irreducible. I can easily conclude the irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ by using Eisenstein's criterion. But I do not know how to make a transition to the larger field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that even in the more familiar case of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, there is no single nice criterion that gives a necessary and sufficient condition for a polynomial to be irreducible. Sure, Eisenstein is enough but there are many other polynomials which are irreducible which don't satisfy Eisenstein's criterion. (Take $X^2+1$.)

Comment: Any answer to this question which strives for completeness (pun intended) should mention [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma).

Comment: Let me expand on @daruma’s cogent comment. First, if $f(X)=X^2+1$, then Eisenstein *does* apply to $f(X+1)$ after all. But even in the complete case, Eisenstein can *only* work when the associated extension is totally ramified at some prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Eisenstein's criterion works just fine](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/math210b-Gauss-Eisenstein.pdf) because $\Bbb Z_p$ is an integral domain and $p\Bbb Z_p$ its prime ideal.